# create parquet files in java

Tags: java, parquet

Is there a way to create parquet files from java?

I have data in memory (java classes) and I want to write it into a parquet file, to later read it from apache-drill.

Is there an simple way to do this, like inserting data into a sql table?

**GOT IT**

Thanks for the help.

Combining the answers and this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=pbase-master/hbase-server/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/pbase/util/GenerateParquetFile.java), I was able to create a parquet file and read it back with drill.

Comment: In the example you provided, you defined the schema. Is it possible to write without knowing the schema?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'm working with a predefined schema

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ParquetWriter's constructors are deprecated(1.8.1) but not ParquetWriter itself, you can still create ParquetWriter by extending abstract Builder subclass inside of it.

Here an example from parquet creators themselves [ExampleParquetWriter](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/example/ExampleParquetWriter.java):

```
  public static class Builder extends ParquetWriter.Builder<Group, Builder> {
    private MessageType type = null;
    private Map<String, String> extraMetaData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private Builder(Path file) {
      super(file);
    }

    public Builder withType(MessageType type) {
      this.type = type;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder withExtraMetaData(Map<String, String> extraMetaData) {
      this.extraMetaData = extraMetaData;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected Builder self() {
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected WriteSupport<Group> getWriteSupport(Configuration conf) {
      return new GroupWriteSupport(type, extraMetaData);
    }

  }
```

If you don't want to use Group and GroupWriteSupport(bundled in Parquet but purposed just as an example of data-model implementation) you can go with Avro, Protocol Buffers, or Thrift in-memory data models. Here is an example using writing Parquet using Avro:

```
try (ParquetWriter<GenericData.Record> writer = AvroParquetWriter
        .<GenericData.Record>builder(fileToWrite)
        .withSchema(schema)
        .withConf(new Configuration())
        .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
        .build()) {
    for (GenericData.Record record : recordsToWrite) {
        writer.write(record);
    }
}
```

You will need these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Full example [here](https://github.com/MaxNevermind/Hadoop-snippets/blob/master/src/main/java/org/maxkons/hadoop_snippets/parquet/ParquetReaderWriterWithAvro.java).

Comment: Is it possible to write without knowing the schema ?

Comment: @7H3IN5ID3R no. you must specify the schema

Comment: Yep, understand it. My case was different, events are flowing has different different schema. I could able convert with python using pandas and fast parquet. Handing over the responsibility of finding the schema to Pandas.

Comment: You need also Hadoop core deps, for the Path class

Comment: @7H3IN5ID3R were you able to figure out how to use it for different schema's?

Answer (score 3):

A few possible ways to do it:

- Use the Java Parquet library to write Parquet directly from your code.
- Connect to Hive or Impala using JDBC and insert the data using SQL. Please note that if you insert rows one by one it will result in separate files for each individual record and will totally ruin the performance. You should insert *lots* of rows at once, which is not trivial, so I don't recommend this approach.
- Save the data to a delimited text file, then do the following steps in either Hive or Impala:

  - Define a table over the text file to allow Hive/Impala to read the data. Let's call this table `text_table`. See Impala's [Create Table Statement](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_create_table.html) for details.
  - Create a new table with identical columns but specifying Parquet as its file format. Let's call this table `parquet_table`.
  - Finally do an `insert into parquet_table select * from text_table` to copy all data from the text file to the parquet table.

Comment: I wanted to go with the first option and to use ParquetWriter, but it was marked as @depricated. So I went to ParquetFileWriter, but I couldn't find any examples of how to define and use it. Going through a csv will be really slow because it's actually tons of data that I want to stream through my app. So I'll have to write it all to the csv and then convert it.

Is there an exmaple of the first option?