# Writing parquet files without using Hadoop and Apache

Tags: etl, talend

just wanna ask if I can create a parquet without hadoop/apache? I'm using talend by the way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: In case you need a sql based in memory way to do that, try out DuckDb. https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these links:
Writing a Paraquet file in Python:
https://mungingdata.com/python/writing-parquet-pandas-pyspark-koalas/
Writing a Paraquet file in Java, this was answered earlier and I think you might have seen this.
[create parquet files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728854/create-parquet-files-in-java)